# Using the same method to instantiate identical object from different namespaces

Tags: c#, object, reflection

I'm using a SOAP API that has issues: there are a bunch of services in different namespaces called A, B and C. To make a connection and use the API I need to use an authentication object with my password, let's call it AutObj. This AutObj is the same for A B and C but I cannot use the same one because every namespaces have their type. So right now I'm doing this:

```
class FactoryAut {

public A.AutObj GetAutA (string pw)
    A.AutObj AutObj = new A.AutObj();
    
    AutObj.pw = pw;
    return AutObj;
}

public B.AutObj GetAutB (string pw)
    B.AutObj AutObj = new B.AutObj();
    
    AutObj.pw = pw;
    return AutObj;
}

public C.AutObj GetAutC (string pw)
    C.AutObj AutObj = new C.AutObj();
    
    AutObj.pw = pw;
    return AutObj;
}
```

I'm thinking about implementing something like this:

```
    public T GetAut (string pw, T)
    T.AutObj AutObj = new T.AutObj();
    
    AutObj.pw = pw;
    return AutObj;
}
```

Where I pass to the method what type of object I need. I think I have to use Reflection right? But I don't know how to do that, and I don't know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using reflection:

```
    public static class Factory
{
    public static T GetAut<T>()
    {
        T autPar = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (var field in fi)
        {
            switch (field.Name)
            {
                case "pwField":
                    field.SetValue(autPar, ConfigurationService.pw);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return autPar;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it would be worth looking at whether your tooling allows re-use of types. WCF does, for example (not that I'm the worlds greatest WCF fan) - which would make this entire issue just disappear.

The next thing I would look at is whether the tooling is generating `partial` classes. If it is, you could do something like:

```
public interface IAutObj
{
    string pw {get;set;}
}

namespace A
{
    partial class AutObj : IAutObj {}
}
namespace B
{
    partial class AutObj : IAutObj {}
}
namespace C
{
    partial class AutObj : IAutObj {}
}
```

These `partial` declarations **are combined with** the code in the generated files (typically `.designer.cs`), and will use implicit interface implementation to satisfy `IAutObj`.

Finally, you can then have:

```
public T GetAut<T>(string pw) where T : class, new(), IAutObj
{
    var obj = new T();
    obj.pw = pw;
    return obj;
}
```

and use:

```
var autObj = GetAut<A>("abc");
```

You might even be able to limit the downstream code to the interface rather than `T`, i.e.

```
IAutObj autObj = GetAut<A>("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue I'll share. We have the same situation, the same object in different namespaces generated from different wsdls.

We got around it using `dynamic` which is imperfect but is another option and a step up from using object.